# Event for back button after AT LINE SELECTION in ABAP list report?

Tags: abap, dynpro

I have a list report that uses the event block `AT LINE SELECTION` (and `HIDE`).

```
AT LINE-SELECTION.
    WRITE: 'Testline'.
* and some more things
```

When I double click on a line in the main list, `AT LINE SELECTION` is processed, and the main list is replaced with a list that consists of the text 'Testline'.

When I klick on the green back button, the main list is shown again.

Everything works as espected.

Now to my question:

Is there some way how the report can be notified when the user clicks on the green back button to go from the detail list to the main list?

The obvious solution `AT USER-COMMAND` is not called.
This is the event where I want to `SUBMIT` the same report again to update the list.

(I know I could do this with an ALV report, but is this possible with a simple list report?)

Comment: Very good question. Even the debugger does not kick in having clicked back button.

Comment: Did you define any PF-Status in your report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you check the [documentation](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPAT_USER-COMMAND.htm) you will find the following information:

> - The function codes PICK and PF## ("##" stands for 01 to 24) do not cause the event AT USER-COMMAND, but the events AT LINE-SELECTION and AT PF##.
> - All function codes that start with the character "%" are interpreted as system functions and do not cause the event AT USER-COMMAND. The system functions for lists are listed in the following table 1.
> - The function codes in the following table 2, likewise, **do not cause the event AT USER-COMMAND, but are handled by the list processor**.

*table 2* includes `BACK` (that's the default code for the green arrow).

What you can do: Write your own status.

```
REPORT ytest.

DATA pf_exclude TYPE TABLE OF sy-ucomm WITH HEADER LINE.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  SET PF-STATUS 'LIST'.  "<--- here
  WRITE: / 'Hello World'.

AT LINE-SELECTION.
  WRITE: 'Testline'.
* and some more things

AT USER-COMMAND.
  BREAK-POINT.
  CASE sy-ucomm.
    WHEN 'MYBACK'.
  ENDCASE.
```

Now you can define your own status:

[image: Define PF-Status]

- Don't forget to define `PICK` - or the double click will not work.
- Define your own back-function.